# TextView Overlapping in constraint layout in android

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

In my layout in android the text views overlapping in `ConstraintLayout` as you can see in the below:

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_version"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/version"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/version"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/version"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_min_sdk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/min_sdk"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/min_sdk"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/min_sdk"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/version"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_target_sdk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/target_sdk"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/target_sdk"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_min_sdk" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/target_sdk"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/min_sdk"
        />

    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="start"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="txt_version,txt_min_sdk,txt_target_sdk" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end" app:constraint_referenced_ids="txt_version,txt_min_sdk,txt_target_sdk" />
```